# Join two querys in mySQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm having this trouble for a while, and a some help will be great! the thing is I have this two querys:

```
SELECT u.idusuario, u.usuario, coordi.nombres, coordi.apellidos, u.email, coordi.fecha_inicio, u.DatoUsuario
FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN coordinadores coordi ON u.idusuario=coordi.Usuarios_idusuario

SELECT u.idusuario, u.usuario, admin.nombres, admin.apellidos, u.email, admin.fecha_inicio, u.DatoUsuario 
FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN administradores admin ON u.idusuario=admin.Users_idUsers
```

and i would like to have it into only one query but I don't know how to do it, if someone can help me it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing is you need to add a Union in between both the query

```
SELECT u.idusuario, u.usuario, coordi.nombres, coordi.apellidos, u.email, coordi.fecha_inicio, u.DatoUsuario
FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN coordinadores coordi ON u.idusuario=coordi.Usuarios_idusuario

UNION

SELECT u.idusuario, u.usuario, admin.nombres, admin.apellidos, u.email, admin.fecha_inicio, u.DatoUsuario 
FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN administradores admin ON u.idusuario=admin.Users_idUsers
```

you can read more about [Union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set.

The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the column names for the results returned. Selected columns listed in corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the same data type.

### **Order By**

```
SELECT u.idusuario, u.usuario, coordi.nombres, coordi.apellidos, u.email, coordi.fecha_inicio, u.DatoUsuario
(SELECT u.idusuario, u.usuario, coordi.nombres, coordi.apellidos, u.email, coordi.fecha_inicio, u.DatoUsuario
FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN coordinadores coordi ON u.idusuario=coordi.Usuarios_idusuario

UNION

SELECT u.idusuario, u.usuario, admin.nombres, admin.apellidos, u.email, admin.fecha_inicio, u.DatoUsuario 
FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN administradores admin ON u.idusuario=admin.Users_idUsers) as Results
order by u.idusuario;
```

*you can also write Orderby Clause directly it would be applied to the complete resultset*

Comment: Doing that a get this error: #1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

Comment: check that the collation is the same for all columns
check that the collation for your database is the same as your columns
cast all your columns to the same collation as your database and run your script - then remove the collations in your query to find which column is causing the problem